# make Simple Fragment always get InstantiationException

Tags: android, fragment

hello guys i just try to make a simple fragment start up using support library v4 here...
this is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment testFragment = manager.findFragmentById(R.id.listTestFragment);
    transaction.show(testFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}

}
```

and my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.drikvy.testfragmentgame.ListTestFragment"
        android:id="@+id/listTestFragment" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and my ListTestFragment.java

```
public class ListTestFragment extends Fragment {

String[] data = {"aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd"};
MainActivity activity;

public ListTestFragment(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lores_list, null, false);

            ListView lvLores = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_saved_lores);
            lvLores.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.id.text1, data));

            return view;
}
}
```

**sadly android runtime said that i havent empty constructor and that my fragment class is not public class etc
what's wrong?**

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Sir Miro for pointing out the main problem in my code through his answer.
I just want to make clear some matters here:

1. first of all, i didnt know that by putting the fragment in the xml layout would require the fragment class to provide an empty constructor, that's why im always getting instantiate exception error in logcat
2. the reason behind why i didnt put an empty constructor in my fragment class is that because from my previous attempts for making fragments i had successfully show the fragments by using non-empty constructor and i usually add activity parameters inside it for context utilization within the fragment class. but i didnt noticed that none of these fragments was declared on my xml layout! and thats when the error start to popped up
3. so in conclusion we have to provide an empty constructor or no constructor at all if we have declared the fragments on our xml layout. but if we didnt declared them on our xml layout then we can deliberately add any kinds of constructor with any parameters we could possibly wanted within our fragment class!

Comment: use   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lores_list, container  , false); instead of using View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lores_list, null, false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass in your activity from the fragment constructor. `Fragment` has a method called `onAttach` which is called when the fragment is attached to an activity. You can set the `activity` variable from `onAttach`.

Try this as your `Fragment` code:

```
public class ListTestFragment extends Fragment {

    String[] data = {"aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd"};
    MainActivity activity;

    public ListTestFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lores_list, null, false);

        ListView lvLores = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_saved_lores);
        lvLores.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.id.text1, data));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = (MainActivity) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        this.activity = null;
    }
}
```

And also you won't need all that code in your activity. Android will initialize and show the fragment for you automatically.

Comment: nope, still error...
i used to add mainactivity on constructor on other fragments and they all just fine..., don't know what's happening to this one...

Comment: by the way after copy your code, i got this error 
E/AndroidRuntime(21254): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File  from xml type layout resource ID #0x1020014

Comment: to include a fragment in an xml layout, your fragment absolutely must have a parameterless public constructor.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the problem, now i know the details that happening within my code